# My Javascript infix to postfix code is breaking jsFiddle - why?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Here's the code, all I had in the HTML section was `<p></p>`

Options were **onDomready** and **jQuery 1.9.1**

```
var operators = '+-*/()';

Array.prototype.peek = function () {
    return this[this.length - 1];
};

function isDigit(c) {
    return !isOperator(c);
}

function isOperator(c) {
    return operators.indexOf(c) >= 0;
}

function operatorPriority(operator) {
    return operator === '*' || operator === '/' ? 1 : 0;
}

function comparePriority(a, b) {
    return operatorPriority(a) >= operatorPriority(b);
}

function toPostfix(infix) {
    var stack = [];
    stack.push('(');
    infix += ')';

    var count = 0;
    var postfix = "";

    while (stack.length > 0) {
        var c = infix.charAt(count++);
        if (isDigit(c)) {
            postfix += c;
        } else if (c === '(') {
            stack.push(c);
        } else if (isOperator(c)) {
            while (isOperator(stack.peek())) {
                if (comparePriority(stack.peek(), c)) {
                    postfix += stack.pop();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            stack.push(c);
        } else { // assumed )
            while (stack.peek() !== '(') {
                postfix += stack.pop();
            }
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
    return postfix;
}

var infix = "2+4+5";
$('p').text(toPostfix(infix));
```

Comment: Did you [debug step by step](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to see how the stack changes and if it goes to empty ?

Comment: I can't, because it actually just breaks jsFiddle - it freezes. Try it?

Comment: Well, just launch it **after** having set a breakpoint. The [debbuger keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) might come handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop, you must add a condition over `count` :

```
while (stack.length > 0 && count <= infix.length) {
    ...
}
```